# How to get full HTTP server with Spring Boot Selenium tests?

Tags: spring, selenium, spring-boot, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I know that when running Spring Tests there are various annotations that allow you to restrict what what runs in the background so that your unit tests can run faster and only enable what is necessary in order to test your code. However, if you want to test the UI with Selenium, you need to run the web application in its entirety (server + DB + UI + etc...). How is it possible to achieve that? What annotations should I have in the test class header so that I can run the test and automatically load the web app so that the tests can be executed successfully via the browser WebDriver? So far I'm using only the following annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
```

If any of you run Selenium tests successfully with Spring Boot 2.x, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Test is used for unit & integration tests. That's what they [say](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html) in their docs. What you're asking about is definitely a higher level test (according to the [testing pyramid](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html)): a UI testing.

[image]

UI tests are not just simple "run some classes with annotations and Selenium and show me the results". So there is no "magic" annotations to start you app for UI tests. Usually you have a separate environment (could be "development", or "staging" environment, or disposable env in a containerized setup) that you first deploy your application (using general deployment techniques) onto and then run the tests. Test could even probably reside in a separate repository.

Comment: Brilliant! I had a suspicion this was going to be the case when I asked the question but I was unsure. Your answer was very helpful.